# An instance of a model cannot be created once relation has been added CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have three models in question: *Customer*, *Company* and *User*. Customer and User both belong to Company and Company has many Customers as following:

Customer:

```
    var $belongsTo = array(
            'Company' => array(
            'className' => 'Company',
            'foreignKey' => 'company_id',
            'dependent' => false,
        ),
    );
```

Company:

```
        var $hasMany = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'company_id',
        'dependent' => false
    ),
    'Customer'=>array(
        'className' => 'Customer',
        'foreignKey' => 'company_id',
        'dependent' => false
    )
);
```

User:

```
        var $belongsTo = array(
        'Company' => array(
        'className' => 'Company',
        'foreignKey' => 'company_id',
        'dependent' => false,
    ),
);
```

I have a problem when creating/editing Customer objects. Here is how to create form looks like:

```
    echo $this->Form->input('Customer.customer_nr');
    echo $this->Form->input('Customer.name');
    echo $this->Form->input('Customer.phone');
    echo $this->Form->input('Customer.email');
    echo $this->Form->input('Customer.address');
    echo $this->Form->input('Customer.post_nr');
    echo $this->Form->input('Customer.city');
    echo $this->Form->input('Customer.company_id', array('value' => $current_user['company_id'], 'type'=>'hidden'));
```

What I do in the end of the form is I take company_id from a currently logged in user and insert it as a Customer.company_id. It used to work without any problems before the new relations have been introduced. But now as I try to create/edit Customer, I receive the following SQL error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'name' in where clause is ambiguous
```

Any help is much much appreciated.

Here is the controller add function:

```
function add() {



if (!empty($this->data) ) {
    $this->Customer->create();
    if ($this->Customer->save($this->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Customer was saved'), 'positive_notification');
        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'events', 'action' => 'dashboard'));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Customer has been saved. Please, try again'), 'negative_notification');
    }
}
```

}

The error is definately not being cause by redirect as it was fully tested.

Comment: the problem is somewhere else. It's related to a `find()` call. Try to locate the exact code that trigger the error and post it in your question. Probably you set some conditions like `'name' => 'john'` but you better do something like `'User.name' => 'john'`

Comment: Just updated the question with contoller action. The problem is that there is no other place in code that could trigger this error.

Comment: Ohh I just saw a condition like you have mentioned in one of model's functions. Thanks a lot. I just wonder why wasnt this a problem before?

You can make it as a proper answer, so I could select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is somewhere else.

It's in fact related to a find() call.

Try to locate the exact code that trigger the error and post it in your question.

Probably you set some conditions like

```
'conditions' => array(
    'name' => 'john' 
)
```

but you better do something like

```
'conditions' => array(
    'User.name' => 'john' 
)
```

after you created the relationship between `User` and `Company` (it's just an example, maybe the two tabler involved are others) Cake started to join the two tables. So when you search for a particular `name` mysql doesn't know if you want `user` name or `company` name because you have `name` column in both tables.

If you look at the generated query (the one that gives you that error) you'll see the two tables joined. If you don't want that join you have to specify recursive => -1

```
'conditions' => array(
    'name' => 'john' 
),
'recursive' => -1
```